# Use one cell for entering values, then record of entry appears in adjacent column

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want this:

Each time I enter a new value in cell A1, a record of all values I've entered appears in the column of cells C1:C#...

What formula set up do I use to achieve this?

Comment: formulas can't do this, you'll have to use VBA.

Answer (score 1):

Place the following event macro in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim N As Long, A1 As Range
    Set A1 = Range("A1")
    If Intersect(Target, A1) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        Cells(N, "C").Value = A1.Value
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to **install** and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To **remove** the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Answer (score 0):

Try this method:

Select the Range you need and enter `=A1` and end with `Shift+Ctrl+Enter`:

[image]

Comment: Your solution is only show the last value entered. The request was for a record of ***all values*** entered.